# Amazon S3: Allow Dynamic Groups of Users Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Is it possible in S3 to allow dynamic groups of users access to resources in a bucket? For example, I know you can [use Cognito to restrict access of users' content to the respective users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html). However, I don't know how to apply some dynamic rule which would require DB access. Some example scenarios I can think of:

- Instagram-like functionality, users can connect with friends and upload photos. Only friends can view a user's photos.
- Project-level resources. Multiple users can be added to a project, and only members of the project may view its resources. Projects can be created and managed by users and so are not pre-defined.
- Users have private file storage, but can share files with other users.

Now the obvious 1st layer of protection would be the front-end simply not giving the links to these resources to unauthorized users. But suppose in the second scenario, the S3 link to SECRET_COMPANY_DATA.zip gets leaked. I would hope that when someone tries to access that link, it only succeeds if they're in the associated project and have sufficient privileges.

I think, to some degree, this can be handled with [adding custom claims to the cognito token](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-amazon-cognito-to-add-claims-to-an-identity-token-for-fine-grained-authorization/), e.g. you could probably add a project_id claim and do a similar path-based Allow on it. But if a user can be part of multiple projects, this seems to go out the window.

It seems to me like this should be a common enough requirement enough that there is a simple solution. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be:

- Keep your bucket **private**, with no Bucket Policy
- Users **authenticate to your app**
- When a user requests access to a file stored in Amazon S3, **the app should check if they are permitted to access the file**. This could check who 'owns' the file, their list of friends, their projects, etc. You would program all this logic in your own app.
- If the user is authorised to access the file, the your app should generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. This URL can be inserted into HTML, such as in `<a HREF="...">` or `<img src="...">`.
- When the user clicks the link, Amazon S3 will verify the signature and will confirm that the link has not yet expired. If everything is okay, it will **return the file to the user's browser**.

This approach means that **your app** can control all the authentication and authorization, while **S3** will be responsible for serving the content to the user.

If another person got access to the pre-signed URL, then they can also download the content. Therefore, keep the expiry time to a minimum (a few minutes). After this period, **the URL will no longer work.**

Your app can generate the pre-signed URL in a few lines of code. It does not require a call to AWS to create the URL.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was something besides this due to the same reason that someone with access to the link before expiry can access, but I haven’t been able to find anything more flexible/secure either.

Comment: If a person was to give somebody else the link, then they could just as easily give them the downloaded file.  So, there's no perfect solution. Streaming content would be more secure, but clever people can bypass that too.